# Shell Icon Extension programming

Tags: shell, icons

In my project i need to implement icon overlay for selected files and folders in a file system.When u right click on a file/folder and select a context menu the icon of the file/folder must be overlayed with a small icon.

I am new to windows shell programming and dont have enough time to do R&D

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's late to answer your question, but this may provide some hint to others or even you if you couldn't figure it out yet.

Generally, you need some shared media/structure between both context menu and Icon overlay handlers.

You could have a map/hash contains the paths of files/folders that need to have an overlay icon inside your icon overlay handler. The handler searches for the path each time is requested by the shell, and return S_OK from IShellIconOverlayIdentifier::IsMemberOf, else return S_FALSE.

Now, you need to find a way of communication so when your context menu command is triggered, it should send the file's/folder's path to a listing thread in the icon overlay handler, where the thread inserts the path in the map that the handler uses to determine whether to put an icon over the requested file/folder.

Do not forget to implement a suitable locking on this shared map.

Another issue, you need to make the map persist-able if you need the icons to still after Windows restarts, where you could dump the map content to a disk file periodically, and re-populate it every time the shell starts.